# Solve ODE by Fourier transform, and versus by Laplace transform?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

1. Regarding solving ODE by Fourier transform, I read [a nice reply by
   O.L.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/376093/1281).  After applying Fourier transform to an ODE to obtain an
   algebraic equation, the reply showed that some terms involving the
   delta function will show up during solving the algebraic equation,
   but also disappear for some  reason unknown to me. More
   specifically, the reply said that the terms involving the delta
   function "represent the general solution of the homogeneous
   equation, so in our case $~α=β=0~$." I don't understand why "$~α=β=0~$"?

   I don't find out how the initial conditions are used in the method
   by Fourier transform. In the solution by the method of Fourier
   transform, are there some undetermined coefficients to be determined
   from the initial conditions?
2. How does the method of Fourier     transform solve ODEs, in general?
3. What are the advantages and disadvantages of solving ODEs
   by Laplace transform and solving ODEs by Fourier transform?

Thanks!